# How can I insert a key-value pair into a hive map?

Tags: hive

Based on the following [tutorial](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Tutorial), Hive has a map type. However, there does not seem to be a documented way to insert a new key-value pair into a Hive map, via a `SELECT` with some UDF or built-in function. Is this possible?

As a clarification, suppose I have a table called `foo` with a single column, typed `map`, named `column_containing_map`.

Now I want to create a new table that also has one column, typed `map`, but I want each map (which is contained within a single column) to have an additional key-value pair.

A query might look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bar AS
SELECT ADD_TO_MAP(column_containing_map, "NewKey", "NewValue") 
FROM foo;
```

Then the table `bar` would contain the same maps as table `foo` except each map in `bar` would have an additional key-value pair.

Answer (score 7):

Consider you have a student table which contains student marks in various subjects.

```
hive> desc student;
id                      string
name                    string
class                    string
marks                   map<string,string>
```

You can insert values directly to table as below.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE student
SELECT STACK(1,
'100','Sekar','Mathematics',map("Mathematics","78")
)
FROM empinfo 
LIMIT 1;
```

Here 'empinfo' table can be any table in your database.
And Results are:

```
100     Sekar   Mathematics     {"Mathematics":"78"}
```

Comment: Attempted example exactly as given on Hive MapR 5 and got the following error

`FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10293]: Unable to create temp file for insert values Expression of type TOK_FUNCTION not supported in insert/values`

Without `map<string,string>` field in the table structure, the query inserts value no problem

Comment: how would it work if i want to insert multiple values? like multiple key value pairs?

Comment: @VladimirKroz did you use the "select" format like this: insert into table student select stack(1, '100', 'Sekar', 'Mathematics', map("Mathematics", "78")) from dummy

Answer (score 2):

for key-value pairs, you can insert like following sql:

INSERT INTO TABLE student values( "id","name",'class',

map("key1","value1","key2","value2","key3","value3","key4","value4") )

please pay attention to sequence of the values in map.

Comment: `insert values` is not supported for my Hive. `insert into table A select xxxx` works.

Answer (score 1):

I think the combine function from [brickhouse](https://github.com/klout/brickhouse/wiki/Collect-UDFs) will do what you need. Slightly modifying the query in your original question, it would look something like this

```
SELECT 
    combine(column_containing_map, str_to_map("NewKey:NewValue")) 
FROM 
    foo;
```

The limitation with this example is that str_to_map creates a MAP< STRING,STRING >. If your hive map contains other primitive types for the keys or values, this won't work.

Comment: A perfectly fine answer!  Only too bad my cluster does not have `brickhouse` and I'm not an admin with perms to add it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, I didn't quite get this. What do you mean by **with some UDF or built-in function**?If you wish to insert into a table which has a **Map** field it's similar to any other datatype. For example :

I have a table called complex1, created like this :

```
CREATE TABLE complex1(c1 array<string>, c2 map<int,string> ) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY '-' MAP KEYS TERMINATED BY ':' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

I also have a file, called **com.txt**, which contains this :
**Mohammad-Tariq,007:Bond**

Now, i'll load this data into the above created table :

> load data inpath '/inputs/com.txt' into table complex1;

So this table contains :

> select * from complex1;
>
> OK
>
> ["Mohammad","Tariq"]  {7:"Bond"}
>
> Time taken: 0.062 seconds

I have one more table, called complex2 :

```
CREATE TABLE complex2(c1 map<int,string>);
```

Now, to select data from complex1 and insert into complex2 i'll do this :

> insert into table complex2 select c2 from complex1;

Scan the table to cross check :

> select * from complex2;
>
> OK
>
> {7:"Bond"}
>
> Time taken: 0.062 seconds

HTH